# Remove attribute and reformat date string in a file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'm able to remove the attribute using the codes below. However, I don't know how to reformat a date string to the ISO format. From date="**20140424T140222Z**" to date="**2014-04-24T14:02:22Z**"

```
function update {

$unzippedLocation = Get-ChildItem $destination -Recurse

# from date="20140424T140222Z" to date="2014-04-24T14:02:22Z"
Message "Remove and reformat attributes"

$regex='date="(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})T(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})Z"'

ForEach($unzippedFile in $unzippedLocation) {
    (Get-Content $unzippedFile) |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace ' crc=""', '' } |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $regex, 'date="$1-$2-$3T$4:$5:$6Z"' } |
    Set-Content $unzippedFile
    Write-Host "crc attribute has been removed from $($unzippedFile.Name)"
    Write-Host "date attribute has been reformated from $($unzippedFile.Name)"
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand where you need to that the replacement of the date, but one approach is to use regular expression to update the date. Here is a sample for one string, you can incorporate it where you need to:

```
#Defines regex with a separate group for each component
$regex='date="(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})T(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})Z"'
#Sample input
$input = 'date="20140424T140222Z"'

#Update the string
$result = $input -replace $regex, 'date="$1-$2-$3T$4:$5:$6Z"'
Write-Host $result
#Result is 
#date="2014-04-24T14:02:22Z"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .net method [TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx).

This method will try to parse any string in a valid DateTime value and then you format back to ISO format. Using this method you test if your values are  valid.

Example:

```
$dateString = "20140424T140222Z"
$format = "yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ"
[ref]$parsedDate = get-date
$parsed = [DateTime]::TryParseExact($dateString, $format,[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,[System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None,$parseddate)

if($parsed)
{
    write "$dateString is valid"
}

$parseddate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
```